# swapping direction of two vents

Tags: hvac, doors, ventilation

Doing a bathroom remodel. There are two wall vents involved. One faces into the bathroom and the other faces out to a dressing area. They are on either side of the doorway. I want to change the hinged door to a barn door and there is more wall space in the dressing area on the side where the vent faces out to it. I can see how it would be possible to reverse the direction of both vents to free up that wall space but I'm wondering from an HVAC point of view if there is a concern with changing configuration.

Comment: Are the vents the same size?

Comment: Yes. The one currently facing into the bathroom is about a foot in from the exterior wall. The one facing into the dressing area is on the other side of the door opening and would be in front of the toilet with a clearance of 2' from the front of the toilet. It would also be about a foot away from the entrance to the shower.